# In java, how can I check how many substrings of length n are within a given string S?

Tags: java, substring

I'm writing a program where I have to compare all possible substrings  of size 'k' contained within a given string 's', and then order them in a lexicographic way so smaller substrings are first and larger are last.

Example: `s = "serendipia" k = 3` 
Should result in `["ser", "ere", "ren", "end","ndi", "dip", "ipi", "pia" ]`

I'm given 's'(String) and 'k' (size of substring), and this is what I came up with at first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        substringsArray[i] = s.substring(i,i+k); 
        //System.out.format("%s %d %d%n",substringsArray[i], i, s.length());
    }
```

Thought this would work since worst case scenario `'k' == 1` and I'll have as many letters inside my array as `s.length()-1`. It indeed works but I'm getting an obvious exception: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

I've also tried using  ArrayList insted of an Array so I get a dynamic size list, but the same problem arose again: How do I know how many times do I have to iterate over the string without going out of bounds?

So I'm wondering, is there a way/algorithm that could help me figure out- given 's' and 'k' - the correct size of my array?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - k; i++) {`

Comment: You're problem is with s.substring(i,i+k) when you get to the end of the string (i=s.length()-1)

Comment: Actually, it should be `for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - k + 1; i++) {`....I was off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// make sure you don't go beyond the String's length
for (int i = 0; (i+k) <= s.length(); i++){    
    substringsArray[i] = s.substring(i,i+k);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/wLSNL1)

Comment: Man that (i+k) <= s.length is very clever and what I was in need of. Thanks.